# strange behaviour when comparing floating points in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, floating-point

the 3rd of the following tests fails:

```
  specify { (0.6*2).should eql(1.2) }
  specify { (0.3*3).should eql(0.3*3) }
  specify { (0.3*3).should eql(0.9) } # this one fails
```

Why is that? Is this a floating point issue or a ruby or rspec issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Don't compare floating point numbers for equality

The problem is that neither 0.3 nor 0.9 has an exact representation<sup>1</sup> in the floating point format, and so when multiplying 0.3 * 3 you get a number that is very, very close to 0.9, and which will round to 0.9 for printing, but it isn't 0.9.

And your 0.9 constant is also not precisely 0.9, and the two numbers are very slightly different.

Using exact equality comparisons for floating point numbers is usually a mistake in any language.

---

<sup>1. All integers up to about **2<sup>52</sup>** have exact FP representations, but the fractions are composed of a sequence of **1 / 2<sup>n</sup>** terms. *Most* decimal string fractions repeat in base 2.</sup>

Answer (score 12):

As of rspec-2.1

```
specify { (0.6*2).should be_within(0.01).of(1.2) }
```

Before that:

```
specify { (0.6*2).should be_close(1.2, 0.01) }
```